# Return array when use .reduce Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

The following function does not return an array but only an object element. I do not understand why

```
  const selectedId = selectedItems.reduce<string[]>(
      (acc, curr, index) => ({
        ...acc,
        item: curr.id
      }),
      []
    );
    console.log('selectedId ', selectedId ); // {"item": "1"}
```

I want to select an array like this: item: ["1", "2", "3"]

Please any idea, who is a problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

It returns an object because it returns whatever the last thing your callback function returned was,¹ and your callback function is returning an object (not an array).

You may have meant to use `[]` rather than `{}` for the callback's return value (`=> [...acc, item: curr.id]`), but if so, that operation is more clearly expressed via `map`:

```
const selectedId = selectedItems.map(item => item.id);
```

*(I'd also suggest using the plural — `selectedIds` — since it holds multiple ID values.)*

---

¹ If you use `reduce` on an empty array, your callback is never called, and so the seed value you provided is returned instead. (And if you don't provide one, `reduce` throws an error.)